# Does a CFI have to be a CFII to fly with a student in IMC?

Tags: faa-regulations, cfi, imc

A CFI wants to fly with a student under the following conditions:

1. CFI has ASEL pilot cert with Instrument Rating
2. CFI has ASEL Instructor cert with NO Instrument Rating
3. CFI is current in all regards
4. Flight will be IMC
5. The Training will not count toward a rating
6. Will be logged with dual given and actual intruments

Comment: "The training will not count toward a rating" how do you outline that in the log book?

Comment: who cares?  that's a separate problem.

Answer (score 3):

No, a pilot with CP-ASEL-IA and CFI-ASE who is instrument current can take a student into actual IMC, and can even log it in both logbooks as dual training if the instruction is on the area of operation described in FAR 61.107(b)(1)(ix) "Basic Instrument Maneuvers" (etc) because that AOA is towards a private pilot certificate. However, this would be a Dumb Thing to Do because a CFI with no -I does not have any training flying instruments from the right seat, which is a skill that takes quite a bit of practice.

The thing that a CFI-I allows a person to do is to provide training on the areas of operation in FAR 61.65 towards an instrument rating.

Comment: The lack of CFI-I does not necessarily mean the CFI has no experience flying IFR from the right seat, just that he hasn't taken a checkride on it. Many don't, of course, but many do.